# How to skip job run in a cron jobsetup if it fails twice

Tags: kubernetes

I have set up a cronjob to run every 5 minutes. Now, if I want to skip a job instance once if it fails twice. For example: if it fails at 8:45 am and then again at 8:50 am, it should skip the 8:55 am run and try again at 9 am. How to achieve this?

```yaml
apiVersion: batch/v1beta1
kind: CronJob
metadata:
  name: meta
  namespace: meta-refresh-development
  labels:
    app: meta
spec:
  schedule: "*/5 * * * *"
  successfulJobsHistoryLimit: 1
  jobTemplate:
    spec:
      template:
        spec:
          containers:
          - name: meta
            image: <docker-image>
            imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
            env:
              - name: personal_access_token_name
                valueFrom:
                  secretKeyRef:
                    key: personal_access_token_name
                    name: <secret-pod>
          restartPolicy: Never
      backoffLimit: 1
```

Answer (score 0):

You must build that logic in the code. when first job runs initialize the counter and the status in a database. when the job runs next time increment the counter if the previous run was failed. When the counter becomes 2 then skip the run and reset the counter to zero.

Comment: is there anything k8 helps with this?

Comment: i dont think so

Answer (score 0):

By default k8s will stop running the job if it has >= 100 missed schedules. This value for the time being is not adjustable. You can set the CronJob "suspend" field to "true" in order to suspend the schedule job.